# IntelliJ IDEA: Integrated Maven builds often delayed

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

When triggering Maven lifecycle entries in IntelliJ IDEA (clean+install for example), the IDE launches the associated Java with plexus-classworlds-<version>.jar from the associated Maven installation.

Sometimes (mostly) the Java launch takes up to 2 minutes before the Maven action starts.

Any thoughts what could cause this? I'd like to use this integrated feature instead of Maven command line calls (which work "normal" regarding no delay).

Network related Java problems might be, I'm inside Intranet, Firewall, custom proxy.

There is no status or logmessage regarding the Java launch except for the time indicator in the run window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem - well - "solved" by adding java as an exlusion for the av scanner (avira).